# Is there any equivalent in javascript for PHP's mb_convert_case?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any equivalent in javascript/nodejs for PHP's mb_convert_case() in special the mode MB_CASE_TITLE function?

I need a function that converts a upper case name or street to a better readable version where only the first letter is upper case.

Comment: do you mean [toLocaleUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase) and [toLocaleLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase)?

Comment: I have edited my post to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will convert the first character of each word in the input string to uppercase and all its remaining characters to lowercase by using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
 with a regular expression.

`/\S+/` matches entire words because it's looking for consecutive non spacing characters, and the callback passed will process each one of those words returning the equivalent word with letter case transformed.

```js
function convertCaseAsTitle(input) {
  return input.replace(/\S+/g, function(word) {
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}

var inputString =
  "hello world! THIS IS A TEST - MAry had a Little lamb and she loved it so.";
var output = convertCaseAsTitle(inputString);

console.log(output);
//=> Hello World! This Is A Test - Mary Had A Little Lamb And She Loved It So.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no javascript alternatives for this function. But in javascript you can use `toUpperCase`/`toLocaleUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`/`toLocaleLowerCase` for convert string to case that you need.
For more complicated cases you can look at some third party libraries. For example [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase) have some useful helpers for work with string case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```js
function mb_convert_case(str, mode) {
  switch (mode) {
    case 'MB_CASE_UPPER':
      return str.toLocaleUpperCase();
    case 'MB_CASE_LOWER':
      return str.toLocaleLowerCase();
    case 'MB_CASE_TITLE':
      return str.replace(/\b\w/g, function (char) {
        return char.toLocaleUpperCase();
      });
    default:
      return str;
  }
}

// Example usage:
const inputString = "hÉllO wOrLD";
console.log(mb_convert_case(inputString, 'MB_CASE_UPPER')); // Output: HÉLLO WORLD
console.log(mb_convert_case(inputString, 'MB_CASE_LOWER')); // Output: héllO world
console.log(mb_convert_case(inputString, 'MB_CASE_TITLE')); // Output: Héllo World
```

Comment: Please take another look at the output. The title case one doesn't do what you say it does.